# Iam trying to convert Wei to Eth and iam getting this error below

Tags: ethers.js

[image]

const enteranceFee = "10000000000000000"
iam trying to do
ethers.utils.formatUnits(enteranceFee , "ether")
but iam getting the error below help me

Answer (score 0):

from your error log: `Error: invalid ... (argument:"value", value="" ..`  I think you're passing empty value. make sure that **enteranceFee** variable contains the value before processing.

Comment: sir iam passing value in wei as i mentioned above  if i just print enteranceFee it prints "10000000000000000" but when i use ethers.utils.formatUnits(enteranceFee , "ether") iam getting the above error

Answer (score 0):

Before passing your value try converting it to BigNumber:

```
const oneEther = BigNumber.from(enteranceFee);
const result = ethers.utils.formatUnits(oneEther, 'ether');
```

See: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#unit-conversion